# selecting certain points to be plotted

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting number of correct and functioning sensors at each 100 runs.

I will get the following plot:
[image: result wrt runs]

The 100 readings taken for each of the runs is somewhat confusing.
How can I make matlab plot

1. At every 5 values (5,15,20....)
2. The average of 5 runs so that number of plots will be 100/5.

can you help in these two cases thanks

if round=10 in the original case will have 10 bars,

With the formula given by @Richante  data_to_plot = data(1:5:end); will have 2 bars. Great but when I plot will get values at Round 1 and 2. How to display that these are for rounds 1 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot every 5th item by slicing the array:

```
data = %1-by-100 array
data_to_plot = data(1:5:end);
```

To plot the average of 5 runs, you could do a for-loop:

```
data_to_plot = zeros(1, 20);
for i=1:20
  data_to_plot = mean(data((i-1)*5:i*5));
end
```

Or a neat way is to reshape the array into a 5-by-20 matrix and take the mean in the first dimension:

```
data_to_plot = mean(reshape(data, 5, 20));
```

Comment: if round=10 in the previous case will have 10 bars, With data_to_plot = data(1:5:end); will have 2 bars. Great but when I plot will get values at Round 1 and 2. How to display that these are for rounds 1 and 5?

Comment: ??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change. for the lat code line @Richante

Comment: I guess that the array you are plotting is not 1-by-100 then? Is it 100-by-2 or something, with a column for 'correct' and a column for 'functioning'?

Comment: There are two columns over each other @Richante